# Custom made Javascript google, change word Open to Close or Open after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a small JavaScript function to open or close a div-element, without jQuery but just a small JavaScript and CSS and it is working but I want to achieve the following:

The div starts always hidden when loading the page (done)

If the visitor clicks on "OPEN"-button, the div is displayed and the text "OPEN" must be changed in this save button to "CLOSE" and so on, depending if the div is open or closed we display the text: OPEN or CLOSE (working on it and need help with it)

Here is an updated Codepen with it:
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/WNYQeqQ

```js
var LetsDoThis = document.querySelector("#toggle");
var LetsDoThat = document.querySelector("#content");

LetsDoThis.addEventListener("click", function() {
  LetsDoThat.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">OPEN</button>
<div id="content" class="hidden">
  When the "OPEN" button is clicked, the text must change from OPEN to CLOSE, all depending if it is open or closed
</div>
```

How can I accomplish that ?

Comment: If your question doesn't involve jQuery, and you don't want jQuery-based answers, then don't tag it with jQuery

Comment: sorry it was just suggested tags by the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if that fixes it:

```js
var LetsDoThis = document.querySelector("#toggle");
var LetsDoThat = document.querySelector("#content");

LetsDoThis.addEventListener("click", function({ currentTarget }) {
  // true if the class is added or false if it is removed
  let isOpen = LetsDoThat.classList.toggle("hidden");
  
  currentTarget.textContent = isOpen ? 'OPEN' : 'CLOSE'
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">OPEN</button>
<div id="content" class="hidden">
  When the "OPEN" button is clicked, the text must change from OPEN to CLOSE, all depending if it is open or closed
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it makes the correct use of the `classList.toggle` API

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues, Thank you! These comments make me very happy. I'm just an evolving junior developer.

Comment: Rodrigo or Julian: how to change to it works with ID=content instead of class=hidden?

Comment: @PapitoLindo, not recommended to use id, there is no toggle for the id, the lines of code would increase and it would not give you this code in two elements at once, because the id is unique for each element. But if you want to see how it would be done, just say that I'll make the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking the text of the button:

```js
var LetsDoThis = document.querySelector("#toggle");
var LetsDoThat = document.querySelector("#content");

LetsDoThis.addEventListener("click", function() {
  LetsDoThat.classList.toggle("hidden");
  (LetsDoThis.innerHTML == 'OPEN') ? LetsDoThis.innerHTML = 'CLOSED': LetsDoThis.innerHTML = 'OPEN';

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">OPEN</button>
<div id="content" class="hidden">
  When the "OPEN" button is clicked, the text must change from OPEN to CLOSE, all depending if it is open or closed
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the event handler to include the button as follows.

```
LetsDoThis.addEventListener("click", function() {
  LetsDoThat.classList.toggle("hidden");
  LetsDoThis.innerText = LetsDoThis.innerText === "OPEN" ? "CLOSE" : "OPEN";
});
```